# How to compare two different rows of two different tables and update a third table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im having two different tables Value(queid, m) and Ans(queid1, an). I want to compare queid and queid1 and if they are same then m and an's values and has to update the third table with correct values. Thanx a tons.
 
Table structures are
 
Value table will have two attributes queid and m. queid will have data like 3, 4, 5, 6, and m will have a, v, d, e
Ans table will have attributes queid1 and an. queid1 attributes will have data like 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4 and an will have data like a, v, a, a, a, c, e, r, e, d.
 
Now what i want is that it should compare the values of queid with queid1. so if we consider **3** ie first value of queid in value table, then it should find all the **3**'s in ans table and then is should compare **a** (ie the row corresponding to 3 in value table) with all the 3's in ans. And the corresponding right comparison of a's is to be stored in some third table.

Comment: And what comparison result is considered to be right? How you are choosing data that have to be inserted in the third table?

Comment: when the attribute corresponding to 3 ie a occurs in ans table... that comparison is considered to be right.  The data which is right will be inserted in third table

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by joining both tables on the queid & queid1 columns then filtering any results where the m & an columns are equal:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (col1, col2)
    SELECT V.queid, V.m
    FROM Value V
    JOIN Ans A
        ON V.queid = A.queid1
    WHERE V.m = A.an
;
```